# Using different alpha values in glmnet when comparing two feature sets?

Tags: cross-validation, glmnet, model-comparison, hyperparameter, optimization

I am trying to see if feature set A can differentiate between two groups just as well as or even better than feature set B does. I am comparing the perfomance of both feature sets based on their AUC in binary logistic regession on cvglmnet implemented in nested CV.

- Feature set A - consists of my actual variables of interest (63 total)
- Feature set B - consists of 3 variables that are already well-established as predictors of Y. I am using this as a 'reference set' in which I will evaluate the performance of Feature set A.

The problem is this:
With Feature set A, I get consistently good results (AUC=0.84~0.88) no matter what $\alpha$ value I use. However, with Feature set B, unless  I use $\alpha$=0,I keep getting AUC=0.5. It seems that in Feature set B, for values of $\alpha$ that is not 0 (thus, not pure ridge regression), the lambda that makes all the variables' coefficients zero results in the maximum AUC in the cross validation, and so this lambda is chosen by cvglmnet as both lambda_min and lambda_1se. This leaves only the intercept in my parameters from the training set, so when I apply these parameters to the test set I not suprisingly get AUC=0.5.

**My question: Would it be okay to compare the two feature sets at different $\alpha$ values each?** (e.g. compare the results of Feature set A at $\alpha$=0 and the results of Feature set B at $\alpha$=0.5?).

I am hesitant to report AUC of Feature set A at $\alpha$=0 because other $\alpha$ values result in better AUCs.. and also I would like to have a mix of both lasso and ridge, thus an $\alpha$ that is between 0~1.